# Can UI Grid editing be defined per-row?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When using the UI Grid editing features, it's possible to specify cell editing parameters in `columnDefs`.  But this restricts one to have the same type in all rows for a given column.

I have sort of a sideways grid, where each row is a field, and each column is an entity.  Is it possible to specify the editing parameters *per row*, so in a single column, one row can have, say, a dropdown, and another can have a text box?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom template, for example this one:

```
<div><div ng-if="row.entity.colType === 'text'">
<form name="inputForm">
  <input
    type="INPUT_TYPE"
    ui-grid-editor 
    ng-class="'colt' + col.uid"
    ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD">
</form> 
</div>
<div ng-if="row.entity.colType === 'dropdown'">
  <form 
    name="inputForm"> 
    <select 
      ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" 
      ui-grid-edit-dropdown 
      ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" 
      ng-options="field[editDropdownIdLabel] as    field[editDropdownValueLabel] CUSTOM_FILTERS for field in editDropdownOptionsArray">
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

is a basic example of an editable cell whose type varies depending on the field `colType`.

I just copied and pasted the basic templates from ui-grid.edit and put an ng-if around each of them.

I built [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RHi1v6Q2vTSgABREs1MC?p=preview), but, as you can see, it doesn't hide the inputs after click so I guess you should create a custom directive similar to `uiGridEditor` as suggested in [this tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable).